# Simulate holding ctrl button and release it after X seconds with Javasctipt

Tags: javascript, selenium, events, keyboard

I'm trying to simulate case when user click on ctrl button, hold it clicked for X seconds, and then release it.
How can I do it with JavaScript? I tried the code below but it not works.

```
var sourceElement = document.querySelector("some selector");
var evt = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: \"17\" }); 
sourceElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
// wait X seconds
var evt2 = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key: \"17\" });
sourceElement.dispatchEvent(evt2);
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Please provide a [mcve]. It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/aLbv1eqo/2/

Comment: I didn't write the whole context. My bed. I'm writing automation test with Selenium and try to simulate the above using executeScript function:
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; js.executeScript(Script);
When script is the code above. And it not works when I run my test. Any idea ?

Comment: The best way to get help is to create a [mcve] with a description of expected behavior and actual behavior. Currently the question is unclear for me. Your code snippet works for me. You shouldn't post code in a comment. It's not readable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running this through JavascriptExecutor, you can use `actions`, for example as follows.

```
const actions = driver.actions();

actions.keyDown(CTRL)
                 .pause(milliseconds)
                 .keyUp(CTRL)
                 .perform();
```

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with this. In my case I simulate drag&drop with JS since it doesn't work with Selenium API. And I need to hold ctrl button while dragging and release it after drop. This is the reason why I need to do it with JS.

Comment: Where in your code are you simulating the drag and drop? What's in your question looks like just the CTRL button.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.clickAndHold(sourceElement).build().perform();
```

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with this. In my case I simulate drag&drop with JS since it doesn't work with Selenium API. And I need to hold ctrl button while dragging and release it after drop. This is the reason why I need to do it with JS